# A table and a absolute table, Not scroll as same

Tags: html, css

The html

```
<div class="table-container">
   <table></table>
   <table class="absolute-table"></table>
</div>
```

The two table has same width. But the showing as the [gif](https://github.com/lyon-liao/blog/blob/master/cat.gif).

Comment: We need the CSS too!

Comment: You can see the CSS in gif.

Comment: No, I can't. It's blurry and blocky. Make a [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the page-with-`<>` button in the question editing toolbar) if you want answers to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry, Those code write By Angular, And I'm no idea to write a stack Snippets with Angular. you can download the gif, and it will be more clear.

Comment: Literally just copy and paste the offending HTML and CSS code (that the browser sees) into the relevant boxes, then take bits out until you've just got the table but you can still see the problem. Like what you've already posted, except something that lets us actually see the problem.